# Umbraco - Get Prevalues from a multiple dropdown list datatype and create an unordered list using Razor

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I just can not find how to create an unordered list for Umbraco.

I am able to get the prevalues, BUT I can not output them as a list on the front end.

My code so far is:

```
  var myValues = umbraco.library.GetPreValues(12080);
  <ul>
   @foreach(var c in myValues){
      <li><a href="@baseNode.Url?category=@c">@c</a></li>                      
     }

 </ul>
```

I am getting back the values as the one

item but they are not split up.  I tried adding .Split() to the myValues in the foreach and threw me an error.  Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `umbraco.library.GetPrevalues(int id)` returns an `XPathNodeIterator` so simply iterating through the values will not suffice. In the Umbraco Wiki you can find a [great example](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/getprevalues) on how to iterate and select the prevalues with `XPathNodeIterator`. I've rewritten it to fit the Razor context:

```
@using System.Xml.XPath
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits DynamicNodeContext
@try
{
    var baseNode = Model.AncestorOrSelf();

    XPathNodeIterator iterator = umbraco.library.GetPreValues(1094);
    iterator.MoveNext(); //move to first
    XPathNodeIterator preValues = iterator.Current.SelectChildren("preValue", "");

    @preValues.Count

    <ul>
    @while (preValues.MoveNext())
    {
        string preValue = preValues.Current.Value;

        <li><a href="@baseNode.Url?category=@preValue">@preValue</a></li>                      
    }
    </ul>
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    @e.ToString()   
}
```

Comment: thanks, i was a little confused about the XPath thing.  I forgot to use the using XPATH.