# How to get the string value of a prevalue in umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco

I have added a few prevalues to a dropdown-list.
When Im trying to get the value of a property that uses my dropdownlist-data-type I keep getting the "key" of the preValue as the value of the property.. but thats not what Im after.. I need and want to get the actuallt prevalue-string that I entered as my prevalue..

Any ideas?

Oh and btw.. I need to do it using C#..

**EDIT**

This is what I have tried so far.. and it sort of works.. but It retrives a list of lists that I cant do any quering against..

```
PreValues.GetPreValues(new Document(statistic.ParentId,true).getProperty("identifier").PropertyType.DataTypeDefinition.DataType.DataTypeDefinitionId).Values
```

Comment: any source code showing what you have tried?

Answer (score 5):

I am using below approch to get dropdown list value as text and id

```
// Node ID of content node in which dropdown has been used 
int NodeIdOfContent = 1111; 
Document docMfsFeedSettings = new Document(NodeIdOfContent); 

int preValueID = docMfsFeedSettings.getProperty("dropDownAliasName").Value)

// Retrieve Text value 
string textValue = umbraco.library.GetPreValueAsString(
                  Convert.ToInt32(docMfsFeedSettings.getProperty("dropDownAliasName").Value));
```

Comment: Checkout this for more information http://nishantwork.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/umbraco-how-to-retrieve-drop-down-value-and-drop-down-text-in-umbraco-using-c/

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of a mess, but using the PreValues object here's what you would do to get an IEnumerable of just the values:

```
...

int id = statistic.ParentId;
var node = new Document(id, true);
var property = node.getProperty("dropdown");
var dataTypeDefinitionId = property.PropertyType.DataTypeDefinition.DataType.DataTypeDefinitionId;

// Cast the SortedList to an IEnumerable of DictionaryEntry and then
// select the PreValue objects from it:
var preValues = PreValues.GetPreValues(dataTypeDefinitionId)
    .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    .Select(d => d.Value as PreValue);

// Select just the values from the PreValue objects:
var values = preValues.Select(p => p.Value);
```

Another approach would be to use the [`umbraco.library.GetPrevalues(int id)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11166305/1110395) method. However both approaches are messy in their own ways.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't need it for drop down list. From [Umbraco documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/radiobutton-list):

#### Typed:

```
@if (Model.Content.HasValue("superHero"))
{
    <p>@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("superHero")</p>
}
```

#### Dynamic:

```
@if (CurrentPage.HasValue("superHero"))
{
    <p>@CurrentPage.superHero</p>
}
```

However, for radiolist, the prevalue can be accessed as follows:

#### Typed:

```
@if (Model.Content.HasValue("miniFigure"))
{
    var preValue = Umbraco.GetPreValueAsString(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("miniFigure"));
    <p>@preValue</p>
}
```

#### Dynamic:

```
@if (CurrentPage.HasValue("miniFigure"))
{
    var preValue = Umbraco.GetPreValueAsString(CurrentPage.miniFigure);
    <p>@preValue</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Umbraco version 7.53, I just did this, to get the dropdown value:

```
string dropdownTextValue = slider.GetProperty("dropdownAlias").DataValue.ToString();
```